# C Programming question - Branching

Tags: c

> Write a program that reads input up to # and reports the number of times that the sequence ei occurs.

I have little confusion with sequence such as `'ieei'` where compiler does enter 3rd `'e'` but never fetches `'i'` with `getchar()`, why and if someone can improve this before myself it'd be good?

```
char ch;
int sq=0;

while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
{
    if (ch == 'e')
    {
        ch = getchar();

        if (ch == 'e')
            ch = getchar();

        if (ch == 'i')
            sq++;
    }
}

printf("Sequence occurs %d %s\n", sq, sq == 1 ? "time" : "times");
```

Comment: Your `char` (and the one in every answer so far) should be an `int`. `getchar()` returns an `int` specifically to notify the caller of an error (or EOF). Converting the value returned from `getchar()` to type `char` effectively disables the detection of errors (or EOF) in input *(or some valid character is misinterpreted)*

Comment: Added homework tag. Please remove if wrong. (no problem with homework questions, especially asked this way).

Comment: It's not homework, why would it be?!

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion it's simplest to keep the result of the last `getchar()` in a variable rather than have an extra `getchar()` inside your loop.

```
char ch;
int sq=0;
char lastCh = ' ';

while((ch=getChar())!='#') {
  if(lastCh=='e' && ch=='i')
    sq++;
  lastCh=ch;
}
```

This gives the correct result no matter how many `e`'s in a row or whatever, and breaks at the first `#` character.

Comment: It isn't purpose to check for '#' inside, inner getchar has only purpose to fetch next char

Comment: @highlevelcoder but if the inner getchar gets a `#` you lose, and nothing in your problem statement rules out `"abcde#youshouldn'tbereadingthis"`.  It's easiest to simply implement a state machine that remembers the result of the last read.

Comment: I agree to the above statement, I was just experimenting

Comment: To add, # should stop loop execution no matter what, that's why I wasn't bothering. Execution/Reading is until #

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to implement it as:

```
char ch=0;
int sq=0;

do{
    if( (ch=( ch=='e'? ch:getchar() )) == 'e' && (ch=getchar()) == 'i' )
        ++sq;
}while(ch!='#');
```

But it uses `?:` and `&&` for control flow, which might be confusing especially to beginners.

On second thought it's not that hard to unroll it:

```
char ch=0;
int sq=0;

do{
    if( ch!='e' ) ch = getchar();

    if( ch == 'e' ){

        ch = getchar();

        if( ch == 'i' ) ++sq;
    }

}while(ch!='#');
```

Comment: If you enter "eei#", then `sq` is still 0.

Comment: You're right. Fixed (with some more control flow in the `if` statement).

Comment: this is indeed very confusing. There is no point in writing code like this.

Comment: @Alexandre Then make your own point, the guy at least showed some effort!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. I just find this code (the first version) very unreadable.

Comment: Well it's fine with me, it's just that my first code worked with eei# so I don't know what Mr. picky talked about, the task is over for more than 1 week:)

Comment: @highlevelcoder [My very first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6238871/1) didn't work with `eei#`. I've corrected it (making it less readable).